# How use SUMIF with month & year with text criteria on external sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

How use SUMIF with month & year with text criteria,

Exp!

I want to sum

```
A                  B                C
Date              Item Code        QTY

01-12-16          86000             50
15-12-16          86021             20
01-02-17          86022             100
01-03-17          86023             50
```

Now i want sum result of only Dec-16 of  86000 on an external sheet.

Comment: I have two workboards,<br /><br />(1) Issuance<br /><br />(2) Report<br /><br /><br /><br />I want sum results on report sheet without using E Column ,means as you used E column for month,year & code, but i want all these in a formula, as you entered in G (=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$5)=F2)*(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=F3)*($B$2:$B$5=F4)*(C2:C5))) (instead of using a separate column or table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.

```
  A                 B                C
```

1..........    Date    ..........  Item Code.......QTY
2
3..........   01-12-16 ..........  86000..........  50
4..........   15-12-16 ..........  86021..........  20
5..........   01-02-17 ..........  86022.......... 100
6..........   01-03-17 ..........  86023..........  50

Where i want sum of 86000 of Only Dec-2016, i put this formula in the cell & my problem solved

=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$3:$A$6)=12)*(YEAR($A$3:$A$6)=2016)*($C$3:$C$6)*($B$3:$B$6=86000))

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is as per the image below then enter the following formula in `Cell G2`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$5)=12)*(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=2016)*($B$2:$B$5=86000)*(C2:C5))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$5)=F2)*(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=F3)*($B$2:$B$5=F4)*(C2:C5))
```

[image]

Here, `SUMIFS` may not be useful instead you can use `SUM` as

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$5)=F2,IF(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=F3,IF($B$2:$B$5=F4,$C$2:$C$5))))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***EDIT :***

If you have to use month name instead of number i.e. if your are using `Dec` instead of `12` then use following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$5)=MONTH(F2&"1"))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$5)=F3)*($B$2:$B$5=F4)*(C2:C5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Table range, that helps you addressing in each sheets of entire workbook.

Assume date field data type is text:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[QTY], Table1[Date], "01-12-16", Table1[Item Code], "86000")
```

If Date end with 12-16:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[QTY], RIGHT(Table1[Date], 5) , "12-16", Table1[Item Code], "86000")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

[image]

From the screenshot above, I added two extra rows of data to show you how this works.  What I did is to convert all the dates to the first date of the month.  Here is the formula assuming you have the result on `cell E2`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$7,--(DATE(YEAR($A$2:$A$7),MONTH($A$2:$A$7),1)=DATE(2016,12,1)),--($B$2:$B$7=86000))
```

You can also move the criteria into another table so it is easier for you to change them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,">="&F2,$A$2:$A$5,"<="&EOMONTH(F2,0),$B$2:$B$5,G2)
```

The date can be entered as text or as an actual date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck trying to work around...

=SUMIFS(TableColumnOfValues, Text(TableColumnOfDates, "mmm"), "=" & $CellWith3DigitMonthInIt)

or

=SUMIFS(TableColumnOfValues, Month(TableColumnOfDates), "=" & $CellWithMonthNumberInIt)

SumProduct gets around that Beautifully. I however would go with...

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$5*(TEXT($A$2:$A$5,"yyyy-mm")=TEXT($F$2, "yyyy-mm"))*($B$2:$B$5 = $F$4))
```

in G2. or as an alternative in G3...

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$5*(TEXT($A$2:$A$5,"yyyy-mm")=TEXT($F$3, "yyyy-mm"))*($B$2:$B$5 = $F$4))
```

Using TEXT to format the DATE of both the source data and the DATE to be matched means the formatting of the DATE being sought does not matter

[image: Copy of Worksheet showing choice of DATE Formats]

Ian

P.S. I'd also have my data in a ListObject Table or give my Columns Names. End of sermon.